# Receiving error when running the data migration tool: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'USERNAME'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

Receiving this error when trying to run the data migration tool:

```
[Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'USERNAME'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'USERNAME'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I've tried the IP, and domain name, as well as localhost, which all receive the same error?

Near nothing on the net regarding this, so reached out here.

I know the credentials are correct, and the Magento 2 store is up, and running fine.

Any assistance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have found the error in my ways, and figured I'd share in hope to help others who may have made the same mistake.

In my case I had put in the credentials for the Magento 2 database in the Magento 1 `<source>` connection.

As everyone says, double, triple verify your credentials!

Comment: I just added the password="password" variable into the source and dest sections

```<source>
        <database host="127.0.0.1" name="magento1" user="magento1" password="magento1"/>
    </source>
    <destination>
        <database host="127.0.0.1" name="magento2" user="magento2" password="pass" />
    </destination>```